# setting up subdomain in IIS/DNS - possible incorrect subdomain structure

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-6, subdomain, rfc

I am trying to create a subdomain in DNS, however it doesn't appear to be working. I am getting the standard

```
Unable to determine IP address from host name for aa.00.website.com
The domain name does not exist.
```

(the above is an indication of the url, two letters, followed by two numbers)
I have set up the subdomain correctly by creating an A record, and set up IIS for the subdomain. I'm wondering if this is actually allowed?

the subdomain set up works if it is aa00.website.com.

Does DNS not like numbers on their own as subdomains?

(edit: aa may represent a country code, although not deliberately, e.g 'en' or 'gr')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need a bit more info.  For example, is this an internal DNS server or external.  Is the domain available internal and external?

Lets assume the answer is internal for both.  You need to create a sub-zone for this to work.  So create a subzone called 00.  That should have its own A record.  Then you need an additional A record called aa.00.etc...

After the zone and record is created, flush your clients resolver cache "ipconfig /flushdns".  You might need to flush your DNS servers cache (non-client) as well.  Then try an nslookup on the record.  Basically, make sure you can resolve the IP before moving on to IIS.  Based on your posting, at least for now, your issue is with dns.

To answer your other quesiton, DNS doesn't care about numbers vs. letters

Edit1:

I've tested on my 1and1 account and I was able to successfully create a sub-sub domain.  So i went to the menu and clicked on create sub-domain.  In the new domain box, i created a record called, test1.test2 which was a subdomain of "domain.com" per se.  After it created the subdomain, everything works for me from an nslook up.  Are you then taking that record and pointing it to an external web server?

Comment: Thanks for this, i'll give it a try. Its an external DNS server hosted by one and one.

Comment: I've added the A records as such: Hostname:aa.77 Pointsto:0.0.0.0 and Hostname:77 Pointsto:0.0.0.0, and 24-48 hours later, it's still giving me the same error message. Does the order inside the DNS list matter? should 77 appear before aa.77?

Comment: see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks eric, yes they are pointing to an external server. (aa.66) works, however i've just noticed that it wasn't set on my zoneedit account, and the 1&1 nameservers were set to prioritise my zoneedit NS before 1&1 NS.(setup before 1&1 allowed editing of DNS records), so i've updated the nameservers, and added aa.77 to the zoneedit as well. leaving them to propogate and then will see.

Comment: Seems to be working now, and turns out it probably was a nameserver issue (DOH), however i'll mark this as the accepted answer because of your suggestions/help, Thanks